# Endian attribute in a config. file

Tags: linux, file, benchmarking, configuration-files, file-conversion

I want to run a benchmark by simplescalar, but when I want to run it by this command:

```
./sim-profile anagram.pisa-big words < anagram.in > OUT
```

it gives me the following:

```
fatal: PISA binary `anagram.pisa-big'  has wrong endian format
```

Somebody told me that I have to do the following:

1. Run `./sim-profile -confugdump config_new.cfg`
2. Then write `./sim-profile -confugdump config_new.cfg`
3. Change an attribute and change the endian attribute to big-endian

but the problem is that i cant find the attribute that does this thing. After I open this file I have the following:

```
# load configuration from a file
# -config               

# dump configuration to a file
# -dumpconfig           

# print help message
# -h                          false 

# verbose operation
# -v                          false 

# enable debug message
# -d                          false 

# start in Dlite debugger
# -i                          false 

# random number generator seed (0 for timer seed)
-seed                             1 

# initialize and terminate immediately
# -q                          false 

# restore EIO trace execution from <fname>
# -chkpt                     <null> 

# redirect simulator output to file (non-interactive only)
# -redir:sim                 <null> 

# redirect simulated program output to file
# -redir:prog                <null> 

# simulator scheduling priority
-nice                             0 

# maximum number of inst's to execute
-max:inst                         0 

# enable all profile options
-all                          false 

# enable instruction class profiling
-iclass                       false 

# enable instruction profiling
-iprof                        false 

# enable branch instruction profiling
-brprof                       false 

# enable address mode profiling
-amprof                       false 

# enable load/store address segment profiling
-segprof                      false 

# enable text symbol profiling
-tsymprof                     false 

# enable text address profiling
-taddrprof                    false 

# enable data symbol profiling
-dsymprof                     false 

# include compiler-internal symbols during symbol profiling
-internal                     false 

# profile stat(s) against text addr's (mult uses ok)
# -pcstat                    <null>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their [FAQ](http://www.simplescalar.com/) suggests otherwise.  It says:

> Q5: Whenever I try to run binaries, I always get the error: "binary endian does not match host endian", what is wrong?
>
> Your binaries are the wrong endian! Either you mis-configured GCC, GAS or GLD, or you grabbed the wrong binary release. Reconfigure the compilers to the opposite endian, or get the other binary release. To determine the endian of your host machine, run "sysprobe -s", located in the SimpleScalar simulator directory.

The file name extension `pisa-big` suggests that you have big-endian format.  Try to get it into `pisa-little` (or whatever it is called) instead.